# libgdx AssetManager.finishLoading() not working

Tags: java, libgdx, asset-management

I've tried to implement the AssetManager into my project. Now i can't figure out what i'm doing wrong with the AssetManager. I've googled, and tried different things. But it seems that no one else have ever experienced this kind of problem with the AssetManager. I used .finisLoading(), but afterwards if i ask .isLoaded it says that it hasn't been loaded.

The wiki tutorial [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#getting-assets)
says this

> manager.load("data/mytexture.png", Texture.class);
>
> ....
>
> manager.finishLoading();
>
> ...
>
> Texture tex = manager.get("data/mytexture.png", Texture.class);

I have this Code

```
// fullFile e.g. "D:\\folder\\subfolder\\subsubfolder\\jpg.jpg"

if (!new FileHandle(fullFile).exists()) {
    System.err.printf("invalid file \"%s\"\n",fullFile);
    System.exit(1);
}

if (!manager.isLoaded(fullFile,Texture.class)) manager.load(fullFile,Texture.class);
manager.finishLoading();

if (!manager.isLoaded(fullFile,Texture.class)) {
    return = new Sprite(new Texture("D:\\folder\\subfolder\\subsubfolder\\placeholder.jpg"));
} else {
    return new Sprite(manager.get(fullFile,Texture.class));
}
```

the manger is
     `AssetManager manager = new AssetManager(new FileHandleResolver() {
    @Override
    public FileHandle resolve(String fullFile ) {
        FileHandle fh = new FileHandle(fullFile);
        if (!fh.exists()) {
            System.err.printf("invalid file \"%s\"\n",fh.path());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return fh;
    }`

What I've tried so far

Run the Project created by gdx-setup.jar ->  Couldn't load file: badlogic.jpg

Code from: Juan Javier Cassani

```
public static void test() {
AbsoluteFileHandleResolver fileHandleResolver = new AbsoluteFileHandleResolver();
AssetManager manager = new AssetManager(fileHandleResolver);
//This could be anywhere else
String fileName = "D:\\blablabla\\my_project\\core\\assets\\badlogic.jpg";

if (!new FileHandle(fileName).exists()) {
    Gdx.app.error("Blub", "invalid file '" + fileName + "'");
    Gdx.app.exit();
}

if (!manager.isLoaded(fileName, Texture.class))
    manager.load(fileName, Texture.class);

manager.finishLoading();

if (manager.isLoaded(fileName, Texture.class))
    Gdx.app.log("Blub", "Texture loaded!");
else
    Gdx.app.log("Blub", "Texture not loaded!");
}
```

-> Blub: Texture not loaded!

```
Versions: 
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

ashley-1.3.1.jar
box2dlights-1.3.jar
gdx-1.4.1.jar
gdx-ai-1.4.0.jar
gdx-backend-lwjgl-1.4.1.jar
gdx-box2d-1.4.1.jar
gdx-box2d-platform-1.4.1-natives-desktop.jar
gdx-bullet-1.4.1.jar
gdx-bullet-platform-1.4.1-natives-desktop.jar
gdx-controllers-1.4.1.jar
gdx-controllers-desktop-1.4.1.jar
gdx-controllers-platform-1.4.1-natives-desktop.jar
gdx-freetype-1.4.1.jar
gdx-freetype-platform-1.4.1-natives-desktop.jar
gdx-platform-1.4.1-natives-desktop.jar
gdx-tools-1.4.1.jar
jinput-2.0.5.jar
jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar
jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar
jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar
jlayer-1.0.1-gdx.jar
jorbis-0.0.17.jar
jutils-1.0.0.jar
lwjgl-2.9.1.jar
lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-linux.jar
lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-osx.jar
lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-windows.jar
lwjgl_util-2.9.1.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read (again) [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA) that i had to set the working directory to `your_project_path/core/assets/`. I somehow forgot that step after setup.

But the asset folder needs to flat, [no sub directories](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=3313&p=16372) (on desktop).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using absolute (full) file paths (because in the provided code its just commented), but AssetManager expects internals (you are creating it using default constructor, not specifying a FileHandleResolver). I tried your code using

```
String fileName = "texture.jpg";
```

and putting a texture.jpg file in /project/android/assets/ and it works fine. Just put your internal assets in that folder, change your file path to internal and it should work.

**Edit:**

I really think that using absolute paths is not a good idea, since not all backends accept it, and even if you only deploy to desktop, it makes non sense to have your assets in a location outside your jar is. Anyway, this code works for me, for absolute paths:

```
      AbsoluteFileHandleResolver fileHandleResolver = new AbsoluteFileHandleResolver();
      AssetManager manager = new AssetManager(fileHandleResolver);
      //This could be anywhere else
      String fileName = "/home/javier/texture.jpg";

      if (!new FileHandle(fileName).exists()) {
            Gdx.app.error(TAG, "invalid file '" + fileName + "'");
            Gdx.app.exit();
      }

      if (!manager.isLoaded(fileName, Texture.class))
            manager.load(fileName, Texture.class);

      manager.finishLoading();

      if (manager.isLoaded(fileName, Texture.class))
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Texture loaded!");
      else
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Texture not loaded!");
```

Comment: I changed my Assetmanager so i accepts full qualified name. But the same problem persists. It says it is finished loading, and at the same time it is not. The relative path never worked.

Comment: i appreciate your help, but i guess the AssetManager is bugged, not even the Code generated by the setup runs.